# EF6 Data Source missing columns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add 2 grids as master-detail, from a datasource.
My WinForms project contains a reference to a class library project that contains the EF Data Model.
[image]
I've added a datasource to the winforms project, connected to a entity in the model. 
[image] 
[image]
When I drag tables from the datasource to the form, for the master table I get all the columns into the datagridview, but then when I drag the detail table, instead of the columns in detail table, I only get 2 columns: Count and IsReadOnly. Please see pictures.
[image]